# Rcpp still cannot find Rtools

Tags: r, rcpp, rtools

I have been through every bit of advice I can find and still I cannot get Rcpp to link successfully to Rtools, even though `find_rtools()` returns `TRUE`.

I am running Windows 7 professional, R version 3.5.1 (2018-07-02) -- "Feather Spray", Rtools35.  I have installed Rtools as administrator and I have tried versions 34 and 35, with and without rebooting.  My PATH variable appears to be set correctly, according to all advice.  When I get the error message about needing additional tools I have tried letting Rcpp install Rtools itself but no joy.  My PATH does not contain spaces and I have managed to install and use Rcpp on two other machines (and even on the current one when I was using a much earlier version of R and Rcpp - a twin machine is working fine with an old version of R).

The key error message appears to be:

```
> find_rtools()
[1] TRUE
> evalCpp("1+1")
```

> make: *** No rule to make target 'file137c6efd765d.o', needed by 'sourceCpp_3.dll'.  Stop.
>   Error in sourceCpp(code = code, env = env, rebuild = rebuild, cacheDir = cacheDir,  : 
>     Error 1 occurred building shared library.

but all the advice I can find for this error relate to situations where the user themself is running 'make'.  I get the same error regardless of whether I run R directly from the console or through Rstudio (Version 1.1.463). Any suggestions as to diagnostics I can run / how I might solve this would win eternal gratitude.

Answer (score 1):

You say

> I have tried letting Rcpp install Rtools itself

and I can assure you that we have no facility in Rcpp for this -- similarly `find_rtools()` is NOT a function of ours.  Maybe you confuse Rcpp and RStudio and/or `devtools`.

Quick question:  Is Rtools installed in C:/ ?  Please try `evalCpp("2+2", verbose=TRUE)` to see where it goes.

Rcpp, as we document, assumes that `R CMD somecommand` works on your computer.  Ensuring that is your responsibility as we do not have access to your computer

Comment: `.sourceCpp_1_DLLInfo` <- dyn.load('C:/Users/wa100/AppData/Local/Temp/RtmpcjDgcI/sourceCpp-x86_64-w64-mingw32-1.0.0/sourcecpp_171475b2130e/sourceCpp_3.dll')

get_value <- Rcpp:::sourceCppFunction(function() {}, FALSE, `.sourceCpp_1_DLLInfo`, 'sourceCpp_1_get_value')

rm(`.sourceCpp_1_DLLInfo`)

Building shared library
--------------------------------------------------------

DIR: C:/Users/wa100/AppData/Local/Temp/RtmpcjDgcI/sourceCpp-x86_64-w64-mingw32-1.0.0/sourcecpp_171475b2130e

Comment: the other line that seems informative is: DIR: C:/Users/wa100/AppData/Local/Temp/RtmpcjDgcI/sourceCpp-x86_64-w64-mingw32-1.0.0/sourcecpp_171475b2130e